# E/WVMExtractor: Failed to open libwvm.so: dlopen failed: library "libwvm.so" not found

Tags: android, audio, logcat

I have 3 .wav files I am trying to play in Android Studio. The other stack overflow forums on this did not deal with the specific message for the issue at hand.

I have tried resyncing gradle files, rebuilding the project, and copying the .wav file from the C:\user\music folder.

Please see logcat below where the errors started

```
2020-11-26 12:46:16.321 5649-5672/android.jw.soundactivityE/WVMExtractor: Failed to open libwvm.so: dlopen failed: library "libwvm.so" not found
...
2020-11-26 12:46:17.064 5649-5672/android.jw.soundactivity E/SoundPool: Sample rate (96000) out of range
2020-11-26 12:46:17.085 5649-5692/android.jw.soundactivity I/OMXClient: MuxOMX ctor
2020-11-26 12:46:17.204 5649-5674/android.jw.soundactivity D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xab4a94a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9fc25600)
2020-11-26 12:46:17.404 5649-5672/android.jw.soundactivity E/SoundPool: Sample rate (96000) out of range
2020-11-26 12:46:17.424 5649-5696/android.jw.soundactivity I/OMXClient: MuxOMX ctor
2020-11-26 12:46:17.606 5649-5672/android.jw.soundactivity E/SoundPool: Sample rate (96000) out of range
```